# Merge rows with same values in excel

Tags: excel, vba, report

I need to merge rows with same values on excel - I tried using pivot tables, and consolidate and I could not get the desired output. I need rows with same columns merged

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    Set rngDB = Range("b2", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    MergeRange rngDB

     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
 End Sub
 Sub MergeRange(rngDB As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngO As Range, myCell As Range
    Dim n As Integer

    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng <> "" Then
            n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, rng)
            Set rngO = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(n)
            MergeRange rngO
            For Each myCell In rngO
                If myCell <> "" Then
                    myCell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngO, myCell)).Merge
                End If
            Next myCell
            rng.Resize(n).Merge
        End If
    Next rng


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Which column are you testing to do the consolidation?  Is it B or C?  Anyway, try this, and adjust the code to suit your specific needs.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
    For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If Range("C" & lngRow) <> "" Then
            Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) & "; " & Range("C" & lngRow)
            End If
        Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]